# Is there any way to produce animation from the history steps in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, video, history

I need a way to produce an animated GIF of what I did while developing/editing a certain photo in Lightroom. In another word, if there is any tool/workflow/plugin that record every step in my photo editing history into a sequence of photos, considering the history steps as a keyframes?

I have just created an animated GIF of what I mean using a screen recorder over the Navigation pane in lightroom, while I navigate using my mouse through the history. it's quite good but it have a couples of disadvantages like the resolution quality is very poor, the dimension of the preview is very low and cant control time between each step in the developed history.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could always take a screenshot of each step, if using a Mac you can bring up the screenshot application, and create a box the exact size of the photo in the develop module, with all of the bounding boxes hidden to make it as large as possible, while pressing cmd›z or undo, to go back through the steps, making sure to click the screenshot button each time, macOS actually takes a pretty high quality screenshot, you could then bring it into any gif making program you desire, even photoshop, and create your gif with custom times between each frame to speed it up or slow it down.

or I can see what I can build in automator to have it do the actions you require, as it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: actually the GIF I have made in my question was made by the method you mentioned. I thought there is a simple and automated way to do it. Thanks anyway for your reply.